# Получаю ошибку при попытке обработки ошибки

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Создавал сервер на express.js и при попытке обработки 404 ошибки получаю ошибку:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Вот мой код в котором ошибка

```
router.get('/:productId',(req,res,next) => {
    const id = req.params.productId;
    Product.findById(id)
    .exec(doc => {
        if (doc) {
            res.status(200).json({
                doc
            })
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({
                message:"Invalid id"
            })
        }
    })
    .then(doc => {
        console.log(doc)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    })
    })
```

Подскажите где я не прав и как исправить ошибку.Пожалуйста :)

Полный код

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Product = require('../models/products')

router.get('/',(req,res,next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        message : 'Request'
    })
})

router.post('/',(req,res,next) => {
    const product = new Product({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price
    })
    product.save()
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        res.status(201).json({
            message : 'Request',
            createdProduct : res
        })
        }
    )
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json({
        error: err
    })}
)
})

router.get('/:productId',(req,res,next) => {
    const id = req.params.productId;
    Product.findById(id)
    .exec(doc => {
        if (doc) {
            res.status(200).json(doc)
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({
                message:"Invalid id"
            })
        }
    })
    .then(doc => {
        console.log(doc)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        })
    })
    })

router.patch('/:productId',(req,res,next) => {
    const id = req.params.productId;
    if (id === 'special'){
        res.status(200).json({
            message : 'special',
            id : id
        })
    }else{
        res.status(200).json({
            message : 'not special'
        })
    }
})

router.delete('/:productId',(req,res,next) => {
    const id = req.params.productId;
    if (id === 'special'){
        res.status(200).json({
            message : 'special',
            id : id
        })
    }else{
        res.status(200).json({
            message : 'not special'
        })
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

Вот так изменил

```
router.get('/:productId',(req,res,next) => {
    const id = req.params.productId
    ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        res.status(404).json({
            message: 'Invalid id!'
        })
    } else {
        Product.findById(id)
        .exec(doc => {
            if ( doc ) {
                console.log(doc)
                res.status(200).json(doc)
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({
                    message: 'Not found!'
                })
            }
        })
    }
    })
```

Comment: Похоже что у Вас отправляеться сначала `404`, а потом `500`. Попробуйте поставить в конце функции `.exec(doc => {`: `res.end();`

Comment: а зачем у вас и `exec` и `then.catch` ? используйте что-то одно

Comment: Так разве можно писать `.json({ doc })`? Я про фигурные скобки.

Comment: @Suvitruf Нельзя)Исправил)

Comment: Изменил вопрос.Внизу показал как попытался пофиксить но теперь постоянно `{
    "message": "Not found!"
}`